# String manipulation in R - removing extra text inside character string

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am working with a very messy sports dataset in R - currently I am trying to return a list of team names from a column in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
dput(my_df$Var.1[1:9])
c("Thursday, Mar 29, 2018", "Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\n                  Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\t  Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t  Must play 160 games for action.", 
"Regular Season Wins", "Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\t  Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t  Must play 160 games for action.", 
"07:00 PM", "07:00 PM", "Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\n                  Atlanta Braves\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\t  Atlanta Braves\n\t\t\t  Must play 160 games for action.", 
"Regular Season Wins", "Atlanta Braves\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\t  Atlanta Braves\n\t\t\t  Must play 160 games for action."
)
```

Call this subset of the data my_col, and here's what my_col then look like:

```
> my_col
[1] "Thursday, Mar 29, 2018"                                                                                                                                                       
[2] "Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\n                  Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\t  Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t  Must play 160 games for action."
[3] "Regular Season Wins"                                                                                                                                                          
[4] "Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\t  Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t  Must play 160 games for action."                                             
[5] "07:00 PM"                                                                                                                                                                     
[6] "07:00 PM"                                                                                                                                                                     
[7] "Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\n                  Atlanta Braves\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\t  Atlanta Braves\n\t\t\t  Must play 160 games for action."            
[8] "Regular Season Wins"                                                                                                                                                          
[9] "Atlanta Braves\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\t  Atlanta Braves\n\t\t\t  Must play 160 games for action."
```

I would like to extract from this the following (where the team names are in elements 4, 9, 14, 19, of my_col):

```
> output_vec
["Arizona Diamondbacks", "Atlanta Braves", ... ]
```

Looking at a specific element in the column in the 4th spot, I noticed that this string includes the team name along with some extra text that I don't want. So my question is then, how can I make the following change:

```
# from this 
"Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\t  Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t  Must play 160 games for action."

# to this
"Arizona Diamondbacks"

# where all the text is the same besides the team names, which are different each time.
```

Thanks !!

EDIT - it seems like the simplest way to do this would be to remove all text after the first \n, but I don't know how to do that either...

Comment: `gsub("\\n.*", "", text)` (where `text` is the cleaned text vector) should help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep("\\w",gsub("?(\\w+\\s\\w+)\\n.*|.*","\\1",my_col),value = T)
 [1] "Arizona Diamondbacks" "Atlanta Braves"
```

Capture the 2 words that are separated by a space and followed by `\n`. then replace the whole sentence with this captured group. if this condition is not met, just replace the whole sentence with `""`. Now take those words with `grep`

Answer (score 1):

The key with string manipulation is to learn about regular expressions, which let you search and get matches for very precise string types. The `stringr` package provides some consistent functions for manipulating strings. For more info see this [chapter](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html).

Here, there are two steps.

1. Get rid of all the rows that you don't want or have data in other formats. You say that it's rows 4, 9, 14 etc so we can use `slice` for the data in `tbl` form or `[` for vector form with `seq` to extract only those strings.
2. Then, we have to get rid of the rest of the string after `/n`. The key here is the pattern `^.*(?=\\n)`. The `^` indicates the beginning of the string, `.*` indicates some number of characters, and `(?=\\n)` is a lookaround that says we need those characters to precede `\n`. We have to write `\\n` though because `\` is a special character and you need a second one to escape it. Depending on how messy other rows with team names are you might need to modify this pattern: the comments have provided a few other alternatives where instead you match the end of the string and replace it with nothing.

```r
library(tidyverse)
my_col <- c("Thursday, Mar 29, 2018", "Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\n                  Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\t  Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t  Must play 160 games for action.", 
  "Regular Season Wins", "Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\t  Arizona Diamondbacks\n\t\t\t  Must play 160 games for action.", 
  "07:00 PM", "07:00 PM", "Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\n                  Atlanta Braves\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\t  Atlanta Braves\n\t\t\t  Must play 160 games for action.", 
  "Regular Season Wins", "Atlanta Braves\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  Regular Season Wins\n\t\t\t  Atlanta Braves\n\t\t\t  Must play 160 games for action."
)

tbl <- tibble(col = my_col)
tbl %>%
  slice(seq(from = 4, to = nrow(.), by = 5)) %>%
  mutate(teams = str_extract(col, "^.*(?=\\n)")) %>%
  select(teams)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   teams               
#>   <chr>               
#> 1 Arizona Diamondbacks
#> 2 Atlanta Braves

teams <- my_col[seq(from = 4, to = length(my_col), by = 5)] %>%
  str_extract("^.*(?=\\n)") %>%
  print()
#> [1] "Arizona Diamondbacks" "Atlanta Braves"
```

Created on 2018-02-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).